# MenuItem set foreground programattically but not in the submenu WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a menu:

```
<Menu Height="28" Margin="10,1,9.6,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuItem Name="MenuItemFile" Header="File" Background="#00000000" Foreground="Black">
        <MenuItem Header="New tab" Click="MenuItemNewTab_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Close tab" Click="MenuItemCloseTab_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Close all tabs" Click="MenuItemCloseAllTabs_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Open script" Click="MenuItemOpenScript_Click"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Save script" Click="MenuItemSaveScript_Click"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I need to change the foreground color only for `MenuItemFile`, so I've added:

```
Foreground="Black"
```

The problem is that the change also applies to the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the foreground color of the MenuItems, it will override the inherited foreground color.